# pgfplots: color on multiple curves

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot multiple curves by varying a parameter using the command `\foreach`.
From that side, no problem.
What I can't do is assign a different color to each curve, color that I set before eventually.

My WME :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% Preamble: 
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Loi de Wien, xlabel={Longueur d'onde ($\unit{\um}$)},%
        ylabel={Luminance énergétique \\ ($\unit{\watt \per \square \metre \per \steradian}$)},%
        ylabel style = {align=center}, domain=0:2.5, ymax=80]%
\foreach \p in {3000,4000,5000, 6000, 7000} {
\addplot [blue, samples=200]{119.268/(x^5*(exp(14404/(x*\p))-1))};
\addlegendentryexpanded{T=$\p \unit{\kelvin}$}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% Preamble: 
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title=Loi de Wien, xlabel={Longueur d'onde ($\unit{\um}$)},%
            ylabel={Luminance énergétique \\ ($\unit{\watt \per \square \metre \per \steradian}$)},%
            ylabel style = {align=center}, domain=0:2.5, ymax=80]%
            \foreach \p/\i in {3000/yellow, 4000/blue, 5000/orange, 6000/green, 7000/red}{
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot [\i, samples=200]{119.268/(x^5*(exp(14404/(x*\p))-1))};}
                \addlegendentryexpanded{T=$\p \unit{\kelvin}$}
                \temp
                     }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]